# How to disable Gossip and Mingle components of Celery?

Tags: python, celery

I am using Celery only from inside Python interpreter, by importing and configuring it and calling its methods - not through any of its command line utilities (like `celery`).

So, I went looking for configuration directives that correspond to `--without-gossip` and `--without-mingle` command line switches which disable Mingle and Gossip, but there is no mention of either.

Is there a way to disable these components from inside Python for my Celery application, i.e. as they say, "programmatically"?

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like the options exist. 
I filled a feature request for it:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2566